# Facebook share image is not showing up

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working on a website for a painter, and I am trying to share a page with an image, a title and description on Facebook.

I have created a Facebook share button on my webpage, and this button (when clicked) correctly opens a facebook sharer dialog that shows

1. the link to the url,
2. the image,
3. the title and,
4. the descripton

The meta-tags I have placed in my pages header are:

```
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.dutchoilpaintings.com/en/works/Italian_Self_Portrait.html">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:title" content="Italian Self Portrait, by Els Vink.">
<meta property="og:description" content="Oil on panel, 60 x 90 cmPrivate collection">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.dutchoilpaintings.com/library/Italian_Self_Portrait/italian_self_portrait_website.jpg">
```

The page itself and the image are (as you can see) hosted on a normal http domain. The image resolution is 800x927 pixels.

THE PROBLEM:

Despite the fact that the Facebook sharer dialog shows everyting correctly, on my facebook page only a link to the url is displayed, but no image, no title and no description.

MORE INFORMATION:
When I run the url through the Facebook Sharing debugger it shows correct values for all meta-tags that I mentioned in the top of this question. It also shows the image correctly.  I have tried invalidating the Facebook cache several times but to no avail.

I am aware of the fact that the shared image resolution does not completely adhere to Facebook aspect ratio recommendation (1.91:1) but other paintings on the same site seem to come across just fine, and none are painted in 1.91 : 1.

Does anyone know why the shared information is not posted completely? Is it Facebook cache related? If so what can I do about that?

Thanks in advance, and Merry Christmas!
Ad

Comment: I loaded that URL and shared from the Facebook button and it looks fine to me. I'm wondering if you have a cache issue? In your Facebook post, try clicking the down arrow in the top right corner then select "Refresh share attachment"

This should scrape the URL again and update accordingly how it looks.

Answer (score -1):

I have faced this problem later and it was a problem with the page code it self, which i checked by the [w3.org](http://validator.w3.org/) then solved the problems list found on my page and it worked